# HP-UFT v.14.00: Object Spy freezes after clicking on "add object to repository"

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am working on terminal server and have more then enough resources on my machine. From some reason every time after some object was selected and i clicked button "add object to repository" the object spy freezes for 5 minutes or more.
[image]

Did someone had that issue and knows how to make the Object spy fester?

Comment: It seems like a bug in UFT 14, especially with WebElement objects. Whenever I try to work with `WebElement + innertext` property, UFT always crashes. You might need to contact HP support.

Comment: It seems it works fine for me. It would be helpful having a sample page where this can be reproduced... I tried a WebElement inside of a WebTable, but worked with no problem: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro